# What's the best way to know the relative position of a point with regard to a straight line?

Tags: c++, geometry

Suppose now I have a straight line in the 2D coordinate system, which can be wrote as:

```
ax+by+c=0
```

Now I have a point, whose coordinate is `(x0,y0)`, and my question is how I can tell the relative position of the point with regard to the line (above or below). One solution I can figure out is as follows:

```
// set up the line
a = ..;
b = ..;
c = ..;
// make sure that b is negative
if (b>0)
{
  a = -a;
  b = -b;
  c= -c;
}
// set the point
x0 = ..;
y0 = ..;

temp = a*x0+b*y0+c;

if (temp<0)
// the point is above the line
else
// the point is under the line.
```

In the above codes I did not consider the special case of straight line (horizontal or vertical), but the basic idea is to make sure `b` is negative first, and then calculate the function's value (`temp`), and depending on its value determine the point's position. I am not sure whether this is a good solution. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your solution is right. Possible optimization - don't negate coefficients, just evaluate sign of expression `b*(a*x+b*y+c)`. + for above, - for under, 0 for points on line and for indefinite case - vertical lines.

Explanation: common line equation

```
a*x+b*y+c=0
```

may be transformed to normal equation

```
x*cos(t)+y*sin(t)-p=0
```

(with division by `-sign(c)*Sqrt(a^2+b^2)`)
where p is the length of normal to line from coordinate origin (O), t is angle between OX axis and this normal.

The sign of expression

```
XX*cos(t)+YY*sin(t)-p=0
```

**is positive, when point (XX, YY) and coordinate origin are divided by this line**, and negative otherwise. So for t in range 0..Pi sin is positive, and positive value of expression denotes that point is above the line (origin is under) and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. I hope the cooked version is correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Corrected version**

You don't have to  invert any signs. Simply inserting the coordinates of the point `(x,y)` into the form of the line `ax + by + c` results in a value, call this `h`.
Also, compute `d = -c/b`. If `h` and `d` have the same sign and if 'd > 0', then `(x,y)` is "below".

```
bool isBelow( double a, double b, double c, double x0, double y0 ){
  double d = -c/b;
  if( d == 0 ){
    return -a/b*x0 > y0;
  } else {
    double h0 = a*x0 + b*y0 + c;
    return d > 0 && (d > 0 == h0 > 0);
  }
}
```

It will also work for for horizontal lines, but not for vertical lines (where `b==0`).

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I do think it is necessary to invert the sign. Take the y=x for example, in this case a=-1, b= 1, c=0. The point (0,10) is above the line, and if we calculate a*x+by+c = -1×0+10+0 = 10, which is greater than 0, but it is "above" the line.

Comment: @feelfree but a=1, b=-1, c=0 results in the same line! Since the right-hand side of the equation is zero, you can multiply the left-hand side by anything you want including -1 and it's still algebraically identical. The only thing that changes is the sign of the result when the point is off the line.

Comment: counterexample: horizontal line `y-1=0`, point (0,2) gives +1 (below). The same line in form `-y+1=0`, the same point (0,2) gives -1 (above)